# I'm locked out of my account because I'm visiting Colombia and FB doesn't recognize my device

Tags: facebook, security

So I answer all the questions about who is tagged in several photographs and it always comes back with:

> answers not sufficiently accurate

when I know that they ARE accurate. They are MY FRIENDS & RELATIVES, for god's sake.

If a photo is unrecognizable, I choose "Skip", which it is supposed to let you do twice, but it always stops right there and gives the above rejection notice.

How do I get back into my account?